# Impossible save PDF to server with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jspdf

I'm newbie here and with javascript & php.

I can't save my PDF's with jsPDF to local storage on server (automatically generated). In the past works, but now I just put Canvas (javascript) into my HTML, and it doesn't work.

Any help is welcome :)

It works with doc.save javascript, but is not saving automatically to local.

Javascript:

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4'); 
doc.addHTML(document.body, function () {
    //this works but not store in local automatically
    // doc.save('test.pdf');
    //store to local storage
    var pdf = btoa(doc.output()); 
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "pdftoserver.php",
        data: {data: pdf},
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();
$pdfpath=$_SESSION['pdfpath']; //heredated, only path and name for pdf (with date...)

if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
    // print_r($data);
    file_put_contents($pdfpath, $data );
} else {
    echo "PDF failed";
}
exit();
?>
```

MY HTML head scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script  src="canvas.js"></script> <!--for paint and sign on html-->
```

Comment: looks like you have an extra } at the end of the js you posted here. Is it a typo?

Comment: Thanks for reply. In the first line i have a function. This } close it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, Put this after your doc.save() or pdf.save()

```
 var blob = doc.output('blob'); 
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('pdf', blob); 
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'upload.php', 
    method: 'POST', 
    data: formData, 
    processData: false, 
    contentType: false, 
    success: function(response){console.log(response)}, 
    error: function(err){console.log(err)} 
});
```

Then create a upload.php with this:

```
<?php

$pdf = $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name']; 
$name = $_GET['name'];
 

if(isset($pdf)){ 
    $location = "../uploads/";
    move_uploaded_file($pdf, $location.$name.'.pdf');
};
```

?>